Read secret values from AWS secret manager using AWS API Gatewa
I created a secret manager on AWS and added secret values as key value pairs, I want to read it using AWS API Gateway with specific key name of secret, I tried to find a way a lot but did not find anything helpful.
Can someone help for the same?
